# Obsolete reference and out of memory error

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Why `version4` method throws out of memory error but `version3` method doesn't throw it, I think in both the cases there is problem is "obsolete reference"?

```
private static void version4() {
    int count = 0;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        List<Calendar> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(list.size());
        while(true){
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                list.add(i, calendar);
            }
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("count: " + count + " | time:" + (end - start)/1000000);
}

private static void version3() {
    int count = 0;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        Calendar[] calendars = new Calendar[1000]; 
        while(true){
            for (int i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendars[i] = calendar;
            }
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("count: " + count + " | time:" + (end - start)/1000000);
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `list.set(i, calendar)` instead of `list.add(i, calendar)`. Then the two methods are (nearly) equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both  cases you loop forever because of the outer `while (true)`.
But in the array case, in the inner loop you overwrite old values of the array (that has a length of 1000). So the memory consumption is about constant.
While in the `ArrayList` case you add new `Calendar` objects in the inner loop. So the memory usage grows constantly : 1000 (first loop) + 1000 (second loop) + ...